# Scaling while conserving ration

Tags: filepicker.io

Upon using the [convert method](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#convert), I would like to be able to transform a landscape or portrait image given the height and width specify without altering the ratio.

From the documentation, the '**clip**' options act as follow:

> - '**clip**': Resizes the image to fit within the specified parameters without distorting, cropping, or changing the aspect ratio

If I have a 200x50 image and I want a 150x150 result, this would result in a 150x37px **resized** image with its ratio identical to the original's.
If I have a 100x50 image and I want a 150x150 result, this would result in a 150x75px **resized** image with its ratio identical to the original's.

> - '**crop**': Resizes the image to fit the specified parameters exactly by removing any parts of the image that don't fit within the
>     boundaries

If I have a 200x50 image and I want a 150x150 result, this would result in a 150x37px **cropped** image.

> - '**scale**': Resizes the image to fit the specified parameters exactly by scaling the image to the desired size

If I have a 200x50 image and I want a 150x150 result, this would result in a 150x150px **resized** image where the ratio has been altered to fit.

> - '**max**': Resizes the image to fit within the parameters, but as opposed to 'clip' will not scale the image if the image is smaller
>     than the output size

Same output as in 'clip' except that if I have a 100x50 image and I want a 150x150 result, this would result in a 100x50px **resized** image with its ratio identical to the original's.

What I would like to have is the ability to make an image conserve its ratio and be of the required dimension (with vertical and horizontal centering if need be). It would result in an image that is not distorted nor clipped.

I understand there are some trickiness to the task as you have to determine what color do you fill the space with (see [ImageMagick doc about space filling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#space_fill)).

Any insight would be great, hope it is not too much of an edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this set of examples in the ImageMagick documentation:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#square

Comment: Makes sense, but here I am asking in the context of the fileimport.io service. I rely on it to enable such conversion, I believe it is the right kind of solution to get there though. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently offer the ability to "fill" empty parts of the image with a background color, so do not support this use case. We are looking at adding it in the near term, and will update you when this is added.